# How can I get the Linux terminal to look like Windows Git Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, git, bashrc

Before anyone says it, yes, I know this is a duplicate, except when I copy/paste that code into `tilde slash period bash(no period)rc`, the terminal hasn't changed at all.

I'm running Debian on Virtual Box (Windows 10). I'm guessing I'm using the Mate desktop because I'm using Mate terminal.

When I go into a directory with git, I need to type in git status or git branch to see what branch I'm on, it doesn't display it like it's supposed to with the code.

**EDIT: The code I pasted**

```
force_color_prompt=yes
parse_git_branch() {
 git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
 PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[01;31m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
 PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w$(parse_git_branch)\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

**EDIT 2:So it turns out my `.bashrc` file had**

```
 if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
     PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[01;31m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\$ '
    else
     PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w$(parse_git_branch)\$ '
    fi
    unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

printed somewhere else in it. I commented that out and now I get branch (whatever) when I'm in a git directory without needing to type `git branch` or `git status`. The problem I have now is the colors won't show up. This isn't a major issue, though it would be nice to have.

Comment: Did you try and run the command in `parse_git_branch` function manually in a terminal at a git repository location?

Comment: @AmeyaVS, when I run `git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'` in a git directory, I get the branch I'm on in parentheses

Comment: Can you update the question post with the output?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to source the file again. Either log out or do this:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably you are missing the `PS1` prompt configuration for your user id.
You probably can use [this](https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt) which has those features and more.

**Update**
Here is my `PS1` bash shell prompt with added escape sequences for the colors:

```
export PS1="\[\e]0;\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\[\033[1;36m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\n\$ "
```